# php shell_exec("script -q -c '/usr/bin/php ./composer.phar show -d ./' ./out.log") is truncating output

Tags: php, shell, composer-php

I am trying to list all install packages, 
Code is:

> shell_exec("script -q -c '/usr/bin/php ./composer.phar show -d ./' ./out.log")

On terminal its save proper output to out.log file which as follows:

```
doctrine/annotations                     v1.3.1             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/common                          v2.7.2             Common Library for Doctrine projects
```

but when I run it in browser, it saving only name not version and description

```
doctrine/annotations
doctrine/common
```

Don't know why version and description part is getting truncated.

Note: I am using script command to maintain the colored output.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `...is truncating outpu` <-- I see what you did there

Comment: :) I guess, its because of title length limit.